# backbone marionette pass variable to view method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have simple situation and can't understand why variable that I pass to function always **undefined.**

```
var ProjectItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#ProjectItemTemplate",

        initialize: function () {

            var id = this.model.get('project_id');

            $.getJSON('service/api.php/projects/' + id + '/progress').done(function (data) {

                 this.renderProgress('4'); //<== pass here
            });

        },

        renderProgress: function (why) {
            alert(why);  //<== undefined
        ...
        },
    ...
});
```

I expect that it equals '4'. In next step I want to pass "data" but now I realize that I can't pass anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loose the context in $.getJSON done callback. Try this:

```
var ProjectItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#ProjectItemTemplate",

        initialize: function () {

            var id = this.model.get('project_id');
            var _this = this;

            $.getJSON('service/api.php/projects/' + id + '/progress').done(function (data) {

                _this.renderProgress('4'); //<== pass here
            });

        },

        renderProgress: function (why) {
            alert(why);  //<== undefined
        ...
        },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're invoking `renderProgress` on the return of `$.getJSON` you can simply provide the function reference to the `done()`method of the returned jQuery Promise. Your code would look like this:

```
var ProjectItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#ProjectItemTemplate",

        initialize: function () {

            var id = this.model.get('project_id');

            $.getJSON('service/api.php/projects/' + id + '/progress')
             .done(this.renderProgress);
        },

        renderProgress: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        ...
        },
    ...
});
```

If you'll need the view context inside `renderProgress` (like, for example, to refer to a view property), then provide `done()` a version of `renderProgress` that's bound to the view context:

```
$.getJSON('service/api.php/projects/' + id + '/progress')
 .done(_.bind(this.renderProgress, this));
```

where `_.bind` is an UnderscoreJS function. Read more about it [here](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).

Comment: I want to say taht `var _this = this;` and your second solution work fine. About first one - I see variable and pass it into 'sub view' (and it's avalible even in teplateHelper) but subview is not rendering and has no errors.

Comment: Weird that there is no error. But what's happening is that you're probably passing `data` into a subview which is referenced by the `this` JS keyword. Since the first method does not bind `this.renderProgress` to the view's `this`, then the `this` inside `renderProgress` will not include your view's properties.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to **this** inside " $.getJSON( " assign this to any variable and then call "renderProgress" method.

```
var currentObj = this;

 $.getJSON('service/api.php/projects/' + id + '/progress').done(function (data) {

                 currentObj .renderProgress('4'); //<== pass here
            });
```

because in your case this points to current object of that function and not to view object.